# Several try-catch blocks VS one big try-catch block [in a thread]

Tags: exception

I've found [one recommendation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx#Putasinglecatch%28Exceptionex%29perthread9), that says, that we should try to keep one try/except statement per thread.

I have a class, that implements Runnable (Java, but it doesn't actually matter). It has several blocks in it each one surrounded in it's own try-catch block with logging and handling. Each block throws same exception class.

Do you think I should widen exception collection creating an exception per each operation, put all blocks under one try-catch block and handle each one differently? Some example of what I have is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/clumsy-try-catch-how-to-perfect-it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you posted suggests having a single catch block for clarity and maintainability.  I agree with that, it's good advice.  Are you worried about performance?  Theoretically, if you're doing stuff between your exception throwing blocks, multiple try/catch blocks would be faster.  But the difference would be quite small, and maintainability would suffer.  Go with the single try catch.

Comment: The thing is that I have a `run()` method which has a plenty (like 5-9) of same try-catch blocks in it. All of them looking like that one I posted. No performance worries here.

Comment: so then it'll be easier to do a single try-catch block.  More maintainable and clear.